# .Net Framework dependency in Visual Studio Setup Project

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-installer, setup-project

I have downloaded the new [Visual Studio Installer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/04/17/visual-studio-installer-projects-extension.aspx) for VS 2013. I have created a the installer without problems, and removed all dependencies on the .Net Framework. Then generated the installer. But when I try to install the generated setup in Windows 7 for example:

[image]

It says that the setup requires the .Net Framework version 4.5 which was nos selected in the Prerequisites before. Does someone knows how to remove this dependency? Is the Visual Studio Installer Project dependent on the .Net Framework even when no one of the files installed use it? Thanks

Comment: It is not front-line support, if someone have had this problem and has solved it, would be helpful, not just for me.

Comment: @Hans Passant I'm creating the installer and my program does not have dependencies on .NET Framework. I don't wan't the user installs the framework without real need of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more that one dependency on the NET FW in setup projects. One is in the prerequisites, that's the one you removed, but go to the setup project's IDE and there'll be a Launch Condition that includes the NET FW. Delete that.